# deploy django channels on nginx

Tags: django, nginx, redis, django-channels, daphne

I don't know anything about nginx and how to configure it to run channels. My environment is `django 2.x` `ubuntu 16` `nginx` `daphne` `redis` `digitalocean` I've tinkered around with my nginx config file for a weeks now unable to get my socket to connect.

`nginx config`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name x.x.x.x;

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

  location /static/ {
    alias /home/admin1/myproject/channels-examples/multichat/static/ ;
  }

  location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/admin1/myproject/channels-examples/multichat/multichat.sock
  }
}
```

I will greatly appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your app through `daphne` (you can read more here: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html) and configure related nginx section for websockets connections:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
```

Comment: Do you know why the static files don't come through when I go to 143.x.x.x:8000 ?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues on my un-managed VPS.

Check this [repository](https://github.com/NecoHorne/Django-Server-Setup) that I created when i figured out what worked for me.

your static location:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/admin1/myproject/channels-examples/multichat/static/ ;
}
```

should look like this:

```
location /static {
    alias /home/admin1/myproject/channels-examples/multichat;
}
```